# Code reuse when generating dynamic variables

Tags: javascript

I have some code that I want to repeat in the best way possible. I'm looking for some advice to an approach. Function, object, other?

Thanks!

```
// There are many #mad-1, #mad-2, #mad-3 etc
// There are many radioButtons1Value, radioButtons2Value etc
// There are many radio1subtract, radio2subtract etc

let radio1subtract = null;
let radioButtons1Value = null

let radio2subtract = null;
let radioButtons2Value = null

if (document.querySelector('#mad-1')) {
  document.querySelector(`#mad-1 input`).addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(!document.querySelector('#basket-case').classList.contains('touched')) {
      extrasSetup(e);
      radioButtons1Value = parseInt(e.target.dataset.price);
      radio1subtract = radioButtons1Value;
      localExtrasCalc(staticPrice);
      parseAndUpdate();
    } else if(e.target.classList.contains('radioClicked')) {
      radioButtons1Value = 0;
      noVatExtra = noVatExtra - radio1subtract;
      parseAndUpdate();
      e.target.disabled = true;
    }
  }) 
}

if (document.querySelector('#mad-2')) {
  document.querySelector(`#mad-2 input`).addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(!document.querySelector('#basket-case').classList.contains('touched')) {
      extrasSetup(e);
      radioButtons2Value = parseInt(e.target.dataset.price);
      radio2subtract = radioButtons2Value;
      localExtrasCalc(staticPrice);
      parseAndUpdate();
    } else if(e.target.classList.contains('radioClicked')) {
      radioButtons2Value = 0;
      noVatExtra = noVatExtra - radio2subtract;
      parseAndUpdate();
      e.target.disabled = true;
    }
  }) 
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [**How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions**](https://CodeReview.Meta.StackExchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: This is off topic since your current solution does not work for all inputs. You should also post what the code is actually doing.

Comment: Ok added in a better title and added in the extra code that I want there to be some kind of function for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some state you're maintaining, and you need a function that sets up callbacks to modify that state.

So basically, just do that.

You can probably do it better than I'm about to.

```
const newState = () => {
  let _radioSubtract = null;
  let _radioButtonsValue = null;
  return {
    getRadioSubtract: () => { return _radioSubtract; },
    getRadioButtonsValue: () => { return _radioButtonsValue; },
    set: (radioSubtract, radioButtonsValue) => {
      _radioSubtract = radioSubtract;
      _radioButtonsValue = radioButtonsValue;
    },
  };
}

const setHandler = (madID, state) => {
  const mad = document.querySelector(`#${madID}`)
  if (mad) {
    mad.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if(!document.querySelector('#basket-case').classList.contains('touched')) {
        extrasSetup(e);
        state.set(parseInt(e.target.dataset.price), parseInt(e.target.dataset.price));
        localExtrasCalc(staticPrice);
        parseAndUpdate();
      } else if(e.target.classList.contains('radioClicked')) {
        state.set(state.getRadioSubtract(), 0);
        noVatExtra = noVatExtra - state.getRadioSubtract();
        parseAndUpdate();
        e.target.disabled = true;
      }
    }); 
  }
}

setHandler('mad-1', newState());
setHandler('mad-2', newState());
```

I basically ignored everything in your code that I didn't understand or that you haven't talked about. Also I haven't tested this at all. You probably won't be able to use it as-is, but I think it's the pattern you're looking for.